# How to load UILabels inside custom UITableView in different positions?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios9

I have a UITableView with custom cells with one UIImage and one UILabel right after the image.

The first 3 rows the label must be at 'x' position 120 and all other must be at 'x' position 28.

When the table loads all labels are at 'x' 120, but when I got to the detail view and then come back the set up I made is working. Problem is I need the layout working from the first time the table loads.

The code I use to change the 'x' position is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoriesCell

    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.categoryName.frame.origin.x = 120
        case 1:
            cell.categoryName.frame.origin.x = 120
        case 2:
            cell.categoryName.frame.origin.x = 120
        default:
            cell.categoryName.frame.origin.x = 28
            cell.categoryIcon.hidden = true
        break
    }
    return cell
}
```

I tried to put the code that set´s the 'x' position for all the other labels on viewWillAppear, but it didn´t work.

Anyone could have an idea of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Post all the code, not just one line.

Comment: I edited the code for the full code I am using.

Comment: Is this inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sure!!! As I said that code doesn´t work when the table is first loaded, but if I select any row and go to the detail view, when I go back to the tableview the labels are positioned the way I want. But I will edit to post the full func code.